# Can I go to London and return on a long-stay visa for France?

Tags: france

I have a long-stay issued by France. I want to travel to London for a week and return to France. Does leaving France negate that long-stay visa or do I need reentry visa? Issued where?

Comment: What’s your nationality?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking about here. Do you want to know if you can enter UK with a long-stay French visa or do you want to know if you can return to France with the French visa? The answer to the first question is no. The answer to the second question depends on wether you have already used the number of allowed entries on your French visa. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: From the structure of the question, the asker has no difficulty entering the UK and is purely asking if they can re-enter France on their long stay visa. Mentioning London is likely immaterial, other than to indicate they are leaving the Schengen area.

Comment: @Traveller we can infer that the asker is not from the EU, EEA, or Switzerland.  Further information about nationality is not needed to answer the question "Does  leaving France negate that long-stay visa or do I need reentry visa? Issued where?"

Answer (score 3):

If your visa is a single entry visa, you must replace it before you return to France.  Normally you would replace it with a *carte de séjour* (residence permit) before you leave France.  If the number of entries is otherwise limited, then the answer depends on how many times you have already used the visa to enter the Schengen area.

If the visa is issued for multiple entries, then you may leave and reenter France as many times as you like during its period of validity.

The question of whether you need a UK visa is separate.  You cannot use your French visa to enter the UK.  You may need to apply for a UK visa, depending on your nationality.